# Which design pattern is it of SurfaceView

Tags: android, design-patterns

SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder and SurfaceHolder.callback. these class and interfaces are used for a multiply threads drawing view. I want to know which design pattern is it used of this?

Answer (score 0):

From [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html) I think it follows the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) in a way since the surfaceHolder wraps SurfaceView and modify it "Allows you to control the surface size and format, edit the pixels in the surface" and the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to "monitor changes to the surface".

Answer (score 0):

It is an implementation of the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Any component holding a surface can "observe" changes to the surface via the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface. Thus, the class holding the surface is the "observer" and the surface itself is the "observable".

The Decorator pattern also comes into play as [@Warlock suggests.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19652536/1369222)